# How do I download using torrents?

Tags: downloads, qbittorrent

I am trying to download a file using the bittorrent protocol but I can't get my browser to open the magnet link in my torrent client. I have qbittorrent installed but I still can't seem to download from magnet links.

A little box always shows up asking what application I want to use and there is a button that says "browse" but I can't choose anything.

How can I use such links on Ubuntu?

And when you go to explain, please explain every detail as if you are talking to someone who doesn't know anything about Ubuntu.

Comment: I don't understand the lot of downvotes although for a simple duplicate question where the duplicate has +21 UP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Click the torrent link to open which should start the *Launch Application* window where you should check mark the *Remember my choice for magnetic links*, and click the <kbd>Choose...</kbd> button;
   [image: snap1]
2. Now in the next window that appears you can browse to and select the file `/usr/bin/qbittorrent`. For this click *File System* on the side pane and browse through the directories *usr -> bin* where you'll have to select the executable file `qbittorrent` to open.

   **Or**, just click the *File System* and click the *"edit path"* icon to *type a file name* manually (or use the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>);
   [image: snap2]
3. Then in the path input box labelled *Location:* type the path of the executable of the application - `/usr/bin/qbittorrent` and click <kbd>Open</kbd>;
   [image: snap3]
4. Having the desired launch application selected, now click the <kbd>OK</kbd> button. This will start the application qBittorrent and you can continue managing your download from there.
   [image: snap4]

Answer (score 0):

So to download Ubuntu from torrent, you can also save the .torrent file to ~/Download for example.
Then you open your favorite torrent application. Opening torrent from file should be like "File" -> "Open".

Comment: I have ubuntu, im trying to download music and movies off pirate bay, but it is giving me issues