# How to download torrents in ubuntu 13.10

Tags: downloads, qbittorrent

Every time I click on "Get this torrent", I get a window asking to choose a application:

[image]

I have qBittorrent installed but I don't know how do I select it from this windows which open when I click on "Choose" from the previous window.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make Firefox open magnet-links in Transmission?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/122930/how-can-i-make-firefox-open-magnet-links-in-transmission) or this [How do I download using torrents?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/410114/how-do-i-download-using-torrents/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the little *Another application...* browsing window, click on *File System* on the left, then navigate to the directory `usr` and then `bin` (this may take a while to load, there are lots of files in this folder). There you will find the application `qbittorrent`. Choose it and click *Open*.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the torrent file directly to a folder then add it directly to qBittorrent. See screenshot below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

as a work around, you can drag & drop the torrent or magnet (hyperlink) TEXT onto the qbittorrent application & it will start automatically.